# pymssql.connect error list.remove(x): x not in list

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, pymssql

I'm running a program that connects to a SQL server through pymssql. It ran the whole week and since this morning I have this error every time it tries to connect:

```
ERROR TYPE : <class 'ValueError'>
VALUE : list.remove(x): x not in list
TRACEBACK : [
    <*some modules where nothing happens*>,
    <FrameSummary file pymssql.pyx, line 635 in pymssql.connect (pymssql.c:10734)>,
    <FrameSummary file _mssql.pyx, line 1902 in _mssql.connect (_mssql.c:21821)>,
    <FrameSummary file _mssql.pyx, line 636 in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.__init__ (_mssql.c:6558)>
]
```

Has anyone seen a similar issue? I can't find a clue about why this happens...

Thanks!

Comment: Can you include the code that is generating the error? Not `pymssql`, but you script.

Comment: the error occurs in pymssql.connect(**kwargs) where kwargs={"database":some_db, "port":some_port, "server":some_server"} 
The whole code before the call to pymssql only passes the kwargs dict until it needs to connect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time, I realized that I didn't post the answer though I solved the issue a few hours after posting the question: I simply restarted the whole environment and redo the imports and it worked!